# Same top-bar as small screen for all screen sizes

Tags: html, ios, css, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation 5 to create a website.

And I would like for the top-bar that shows up for screen sizes to show on all screen sizes: small, medium, large, x-large. Currently it only show for small screen sizes.

I would like the attached sample of the top-nav to show up for all screen sizes.

So where in the CSS code do I need to make changes to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right what you're looking for consists of expressing width of html elements with percentage instead of px or em. 
Moreover it's reasonable to declare min-width and min-height in order to keep the contained elements in.

Comment: Yes, the Css code provided by Foundation has fixed width for small, medium, large and x-large screens. But I can't figure out what values to change within the code so that only the top-nav elements have the same behaviors for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two bars (tab bar & top bar). As I understood you want to have the tab bar always visible. Your tab bar has a class:

```
show-for-small-only
```

You should remove the class and also remove the top bar.